# Show $F_1$ is a continuous linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X,||\cdot ||)=(C[0,1],||\cdot ||_{\infty})$ and $F_1 :X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by $$F_1 (f)=\int _{1/2}^{3/4} f(t) dt$$ Show $F_1$ is a continuous linear functional.

---

So we need to show it is a linear functional first and then show it is continuous. By our lecture notes, if we show it is continuous at $0$, then it is continuous everywhere. So then the question is done.

Linear functional: Let $a \in \mathbb R$ and $f,g \in X$. Then $$F_1(af+g)=\int _{1/2}^{3/4} (af+g)(t) \, \, dt = \int _{1/2}^{3/4} af(t)+g(t) \, \, dt=\int _{1/2}^{3/4} af(t) dt + \int _{1/2}^{3/4} g(t) dt$$ $$ = a \int _{1/2}^{3/4} f(t) dt + \int _{1/2}^{3/4} g(t) dt = aF_1 (f) + F_1 (g)$$ So it is a linear functional.

Prove that it is continuous at $f=0$: Need to prove $$\forall \varepsilon >0, \, \exists \delta >0: \, ||F_1(f)-F_1(0) ||_{X^{*}} < \varepsilon \, , \text{whenever} \,  ||f-0||_{\infty}$$ So $$||F_1 (f) ||_{X^{*}} = \sup _{f \in X, \, \, ||f||_{\infty}<\delta} \bigg( | \int _{1/2}^{3/4} f(t) dt | : ||t ||_{\infty}\leq 1 \bigg) = \sup _{f \in X, \, \, ||f||_{\infty}<\delta} \bigg(  \int _{1/2}^{3/4} |f(t)| dt  : ||t ||_{\infty}\leq 1 \bigg) \leq  \int _{1/2}^{3/4} \delta dt  =\frac14 \delta < \delta = \varepsilon$$ We let $\delta = \varepsilon$.

Is this correct? I have a feeling I made some notation errors somewhere.

Comment: Some 6 lines before the end, to the right, I think you may have meant  " ...whenever $\;||f-0||_\infty<\delta\;$"

Comment: You have all the correct ideas. I wouldn't say there are really any mistakes in the reasoning, but you're right, there are some notational mistakes.To prove it is continuous, you need to prove that $$\lvert F_1(f) - F_1(0) \rvert < \varepsilon \,\,\,\,\, \text{ when } \,\,\,\,\, \| f - 0 \|_\infty < \delta.$$ Remember, when $f \in X$, we have $F_1(f) \in \mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$ if you are looking at functions mapping into $\mathbb C$). The notation $\| F_1 \|_{X^*}$ means the norm of $F_1$ as a member of the dual space. Writing $\| F_1(f) \|_{X^*}$ where $f \in X$ has no meaning.

Comment: And please just leave away $\|t\|_\infty\le 1$. It has no meaning either. Just leave it away.

Comment: Other than that, your proof goes off without a hitch. We see that $$\lvert F_1(f) \rvert = \left \lvert \int^{3/4}_{1/2} f(x) dx \right \rvert \le \int^{3/4}_{1/2} \lvert f(x) \rvert dx \le \frac 1 4 \delta$$ when $\| f \|_\infty < \delta$ so yes, taking $\delta = \epsilon$ works just fine.

Comment: @User8128 Thanks a lot for your comments. Just wondering, what would $||F_1||_{X^{*}}$ be??? It would be equal to $\sup \{|F_1 (f) | : ||f||_{\infty} \leq 1 \} \leq 1/4$ ? By theorem, it is equivalent to choose $||f||_{\infty}$ to be $=1$ or $<1$ or $\leq 1 $. I chose it to be less of equal to 1 so it is 1/4. But if I choose it to be =1, then it =1/4. And <1 means <1/4????

Comment: Yes I believe so. $\| F_1 \|_{X^*}$ is the smallest non-negative constant $C$ such that $\lvert F_1(f) \rvert \le C \| f \|_\infty$ for all $f \in X$. Here, we certainly proved that $1/4$ works as such a $C$ so yes, $\| F_1 \|_{X^*} \le 1/4$. To see that is actually is $1/4$, we can take a continuous function $f \le 1$ with $f = 1$ on $[1/2, 3/4]$. Then $\lvert F_1(f) \rvert = 1/4 = (1/4) \| f \|_\infty$. This shows that $\| F_1 \|_{X^*} \ge 1/4$. Thus $\| F_1 \|_{X^*} = 1/4$.

Comment: @User8128 What do you mean by $f=1$ on $[1/2 , 3/4]$?

Comment: I'll put it in an answer because it's a bit long for a comment./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the norm of $F_1$ is $1/4$, we can go back to the definition $$\| F_1 \|_{X^*} = \sup \{ \lvert F_1(f) \rvert : \| f \|_\infty \le 1\}.$$ For $f \in X$, with $\| f \|_\infty \le 1$, we have $$\lvert F_1(f) \rvert = \left \lvert \int^{3/4}_{1/2} f(x) dx \right \rvert \le \int^{3/4}_{1/2} \lvert f(x) \rvert dx \le \int^{3/4}_{1/2} 1 dx = \frac 1 4.$$ Since this holds for all $f$ with $\| f \|_{\infty} \le 1$, we have $\| F_1 \|_{X^*} \le \frac 1 4.$

Now define $$g(x) = \left \{\begin{matrix}2x, & 0 \le x \le 1/2, \\ 1, & 1/2 \le x \le 3/4, \\ 4(1-x), & 3/4 \le x \le 1. \end{matrix} \right.$$ Then $g$ is continuous so $g \in X$; also $\| g \|_\infty = 1$. Since $\| F_1 \|_{X^*}$ is the supremum of $\lvert F_1(f) \rvert$ over such functions, in particular. we must have $\| F_1 \|_{X^*} \ge \lvert F_1(g) \rvert$. We see $$\lvert F_1(g) \rvert = \left \lvert \int^{3/4}_{1/2} g(x) dx \right \rvert$$ but between $1/2$ and $3/4$, this $g$ is just the constant $1$. Thus $$\lvert F_1(g) \rvert = \left \lvert \int^{3/4}_{1/2} 1 dx \right \rvert = \frac 1 4.$$ Hence, $\| F_1 \|_{X^*} \ge \frac 1 4.$ Thus $\| F_1 \|_{X^*} = \frac 1 4.$

Comment: on g definition, some of you inequalities are meant to be strict right?

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter. I suppose that yes I should've made some strict, but I constructed it so that the pieces agree at those points so they can be strict or non-strict.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ choose $\;\delta=4\epsilon\;$ , so that

$$||f-0||_\infty\iff ||f||_\infty<\delta\implies\left\|\int_{1/2}^{3/4}f(t)dt\right\|\le\int_{1/2}^{3/4}||f(t)||dt\le\delta\int_{1/2}^{3/4}dt=\frac14\delta=\epsilon$$